# Does there exist an explicit formula for the underlying object of a coproduct of coherently associative algebras?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Lurie shows in "Higher Algebra", that the underlying object of a coproduct of commutative algebras in a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category can be computed as the tensor product of the underlying objects like in classical algebra. Does there exist a similarly explicit description of the underlying object of a coproduct of associative algebras in a monoidal $\infty$-category?